# How to limit user permissions on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So i'm able to freely add users on to Jenkins. However, it seems that for some reason, i can't limit permissions for these users.

Currently, any added user can see any Jenkins job and trigger ANY of these jobs/tasks.

I couldn't find any documentation nor anything in "Manager Users" nor Credentials tab on Jenkins for how to restrict certain jobs to certain users.

is this even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ofcourse It is possible.

Install this plugin - **Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin**

**Manage Jenkins --> Configure global Security --> Enable 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy'**

Now by default admin will have access to all the jobs.

If you want someone to have access to specific job, go to the job details page & Enable 'Enable project-based security'. add the user & give appropriate access.

All other users - can view jobs for which they have been given access.

Comment: hmmm... it looks like i already have this plugin. but how do i activate this "matrix" to select which user sees which jobs?

Comment: You have admin access? if yes, go to Manage Jenkins --> Configure global Security --> Enable 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy'

Comment: oh yeah i see it. Initially it was "anyone can do anything". hahahaha. thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot find `Enable project-based security` button. Where is it?

Comment: @brian you should have admin access. if you have, Manage Jenkins --> Configure global Security